# use Manytomanyfield inputs in a model  to create get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django, forms

I have to create get_absolute_url from an input given into a manytomanyfield. 
Here is the relevant model.

```
    class ConnectTag(models.Models):
       whitetags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='whitectags')
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
       user = models.ForeignField(User, related_name='directconnecttags')
       detail = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def get_absolute_url:
       return "%s.%s.%s...." %tag1,%tag2 ,%tagn
```

where tag1,tag2,tag3 are whitetags. How do I rewrite the last line into actual code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you're asking, but this might help:

```
return '.'.join(self.whitetags.values_list('fieldname', flat=True))
```

where `fieldname` is the field name on the Tag model which you want to output.